# React - How render a component only on some exact route path?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, routes, react-router

I'm a beginner on react and I have the next problem that I can't solve yet:
I want to render an `<NavBar/>` in every routes components but the Home. I have the following code that doesn't solve anything:

```
const App = props => {

  function getBar() {
    if(props.location === "/"){
      return <NavBar/>
    }
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        {getBar()}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/feed" component={Feed} />
          <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
          <Route path="/newPost" component={NewPost}/>
        </Switch>   
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `pathname`:

```
if (props.location.pathname === "/") {
```

or create a new `Route` and specify exactly where you want it to be rendered:

```
<Route path={['/feed', '/profile', ...]} exact component={Navbar} />
```

**Note**: remember to keep it outside the `Switch`.

Comment: Hi kind user. Thank you for your answer! The second solution works, but not the first. What I'm doing wrong in my getBar() function?

Comment: The navbar doesn't render in any path.

Comment: @PedroRelvas Add `console.log(props.location)` and show me

Comment: it returns "undefined".

Comment: @PedroRelvas Wrap your App component with HOC `withRouter` or use `window.location.pathname` instead

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
{getBar()}
```

with

```
{window.location.pathname !== "/" && getBar()}
```